# In a UIView dealloc method do you dealloc your properties BEFORE or AFTER [super dealloc]?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, memory-management

I have a custom UIView which gets loaded through a NIB inside a UIViewController.

I've been struggling with a *-[UIScrollView retainCount]: message sent to deallocated instance* error all day.

My custom UIView subclass dealloc method looked like this:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [myScrollView dealloc];
    [someProperty dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The problem was that it was **always** crashing on [super dealloc] because of the [myScrollView dealloc] preceding it.

When I changed the method around to:

```
-(void)dealloc {
   [super dealloc];
   [myScrollView dealloc];
   [someProperty dealloc];
}
```

Everything is working fine. My question is, does it make a difference if [super dealloc] is called first or last? In most examples I see it called last.

Comment: Why are you calling `retainCount`?  You should *never* call retainCount.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[super dealloc]` should always be the last call in `dealloc`. Your problem is that you should be calling `release` on the other objects, not `dealloc`. `dealloc` is called by the runtime when the release count of the object reaches zero, your code should never call it directly.

Your code should therefore actually look like:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [myScrollView release];
    [someProperty release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```